# How to append object name with variable string in php?

Tags: php, string, object, foreach

I have some array of objects like this

```
$names=Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 
                                        [heading_de] => Title_Deutch 
                                        [heading_en] => Title_English );
```

And i have some var like

```
$lang="_en";
```

When i want to try something like this

```
foreach ($names as $title)
        {

         $title = $title->heading.$lang;
        }
```

I only got

```
$title="_en"
```

But when i try something like this

```
foreach ($names as $title)
        {

         $title = $title->heading_en;
        }
```

I got it ok, where is my mistake, hot to combine string and object ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`$title->{'heading' . $lang}`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use variable variables in php, try the following

```
  $lang = "_en";
  foreach ($names as $title) {
    echo $title->{'heading' . $lang};
  }
```